# 2019 incorrect week calculation by the standard date format mask

Tags: r, bugzilla

Normally I calculate the week of the year by the standard date format mask `%Y%W`. Till 2019 it worked quite good but last days I've noticed that the first week of the year 2019 (2018/12/31-2019/01/06) is shown like the last week number 53 from 2018. And only the week 2019/01/07-2019/01/13 is the first week of 2019. I've checked if it's correct.

Everywhere you can see that the week 2018/12/31-2019/01/06 is currently the first week of 2019. And even Oracle knows it `to_char(..., 'yyyyiw')`, but R doesn't. At least it should have the same opinion.

It does matter for me and I think it looks like a bug.
I'm using R 3.5.0.

Answer (score 1):

See `?strftime`:

> ```
>  ‘%U’ Week of the year as decimal number (00-53) using Sunday as
>       the first day 1 of the week (and typically with the first
>       Sunday of the year as day 1 of week 1).  The US convention.
>
>  ‘%V’ Week of the year as decimal number (01-53) as defined in ISO
>       8601.  If the week (starting on Monday) containing 1 January
>       has four or more days in the new year, then it is considered
>       week 1.  Otherwise, it is the last week of the previous year,
>       and the next week is week 1.  (Accepted but ignored on
>       input.)
>
>  ‘%W’ Week of the year as decimal number (00-53) using Monday as
>       the first day of week (and typically with the first Monday of
>       the year as day 1 of week 1).  The UK convention.
> ```

The format mask IW in Oracle returns the [ISO week number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) of the year, i.e. `%V` in R:

```
R> x <- as.Date("2018-12-28") + 0:10
R> data.frame(date=x, weeknum=format(x, "%V"))
         date weeknum
1  2018-12-28      52
2  2018-12-29      52
3  2018-12-30      52
4  2018-12-31      01
5  2019-01-01      01
6  2019-01-02      01
7  2019-01-03      01
8  2019-01-04      01
9  2019-01-05      01
10 2019-01-06      01
11 2019-01-07      02
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know about the mask with %V. It's not always present in the date format descriptions, you can find on the internet. I didn't know there's something else. It was also confusing that the %W mask has worked very well in 2018. Anyway thanks!